# Java magnetic card reader APIs for integrating with Java EE web applications

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, magnetic-cards

I am developing a web application in Java that needs interfacing with magnetic card readers.

I have been searching for quite sometime and I don't see a solution. I have seen .NET APIs available for these. I am looking for an open source solution that I can use to integrate with my web application.

Comment: We've been running something similar a while ago. The device was being communicated with over a serial connection and Java Comm. API and it's newer cousin, Rx/Tx library were two initial choices. Both libraries were performing very bad, and we came up with no choice but to write the communications code in C and plug it into our Java environment using JNA (Java Native Access), where we had our main business logic. JNA performed really well and it's very "clean" and easy to use.

Comment: Thanks Arash! I'll see how to fit that in.